# Disable default border in IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I m really getting pissed with default border being rendered for elements in IE7. Even after setting browser property to none or 0 
and even after writing conditional css using if else IE7 has another stylesheet(non-ie) being active. why?
my conditional css looks like

```
<html>
  <head>
        <!--[if  IE 7]><!-->        
            <link href="CSS/ie7stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
        <!--<![endif]-->
        <!--[if  !IE]><!-->        
            <link href="CSS/ie7stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
        <!--<![endif]-->
  </head>
</html>
```

my styles look like this
css code

```
html>body
{
    *margin: 0;
    *padding: 0;
    *-webkit-border: 0\;
    *font-size: 100%;
    *font: inherit;
    *font-family: 'arial' sans-serif;
    *vertical-align: baseline;
    *border: none;
}
```

and even font (arial sans-serif)are nor getting rendered. 
kindly help
Thanks

Comment: What is the _browser property_? Do you mean _border property_?

Comment: What default border for what elements? Show an actual example and point at the element(s) you are talking about.

Comment: am sorry @barmar its actually border got it now

Comment: @Jukka every div element in the page has a border when it is displayed in IE7. even being styled as border :0 ;

Comment: Then you have some CSS that sets such borders, or some browser add-on. It’s pointless to ask others to debug your code when you don’t even show the code.

Answer (score 0):

Either you are using an advanced/unusual css syntax that im not familiar with, or your css code is invalid. To target all elements in the body, use:

```
html > body * {
    margin: 0; /* Or whatever attr/vals you desire */
}
```

And dont use asterisks next to the attribute names as you have done.

IE only tends to put borders on images and links, so this might be a better combination of selectors, attributes and values for your purposes:

```
a,
a:active,
a:selected,
a:visited,
img { 
    border: none;
    outline: none; /* Removes dotted border that appears when item is selected */
}
```

Comment: asterisks are needed to enable styles in IE 7